# How to prove properties about mixed (discrete and continuous inputs) function spaces?

Tags: convergence, gaussian-process, functional-data-analysis, mixed-type-data

I am using Gaussian Processes for data with mixed inputs (discrete and continuous input variables) i.e. $=[_,_]$ where $_ \in \Re$ and $x_d \in \mathbb{Z}$. There is a lot of work on analyzing Gaussian processes in [continuous](https://arxiv.org/abs/0912.3995) [spaces](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1807.02582.pdf) but I couldn't find anything related on mixed or discrete inputs. How do people theoretically analyze properties of gaussian processes/kernel methods (or in general function spaces) over mixed data?

Comment: This seems a bit broad. Can you say more specifically what you're trying to do?

Comment: Specifically, I am trying to prove regret bounds for Gaussian process based bandit optimization. In the continuous case, there are many such regret bounds [for e.g. see https://arxiv.org/abs/0912.3995 ] . However, most of them require knowing the kinds of functions generated by the kernels defined over continuous spaces (for e.g. lipschitz continuous, differentiable etc.). I was wondering if there was a similar counterpart for understanding properties of functions defined over mixed spaces so that I can capture those assumptions in appropriate kernels.